# Sort by sum of value property (if it is equal true) of Map Object in mongo db query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to sort a collection, which has a nested Object of type `HashMap` as defined in `Java` by sum of Map values (in case the value is true).

I've tried:

```
db.blogposts.aggregate(
     [                       
         { $group: { _id: 1, total: { $sum: {$cond: { if: { $eq: 
              [ 
                 "$upvoteUserIds.value", "true" 
              ] 
          }, then: 1, else: 0 } } } } },
          { $sort: { total: -1, _id: -1 } },
          { $limit: 2 }
      ]
)

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d507c400605ba68a4932cd7"),
    "userId" : 10,
    "name" : "name10",
    "text" : "text10",
    "upvoteUserIds" : {
        "1" : true,
        "2" : true,
        "3" : true,
        "4" : false,
        "5" : false
    },

}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d508bdb0605ba68a4932cda"),
    "userId" : 5,
    "name" : "popular",
    "text" : "text",
    "upvoteUserIds" : {
        "1" : true,
        "2" : true,
        "4" : false
    },    
}
```

upvoteUserIds in Java:

```
private Map<Integer, Boolean> upvoteUserIds = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

I always get 0 for total:

```
{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "total" : 0.0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a hashmap field then it would be better to convert the hashmap to an array of key value field pairs using **[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)**. Armed with this array, **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)** on the true elements and then get the **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)** of the filtered array that should act as your count.

The above can be expressed with the following pipeline

```
db.blogposts.aggregate([         
    { '$addFields': {
        'total': {
            '$size': {
                '$filter': {
                    'input': { '$objectToArray': '$upvoteUserIds' },
                    'cond': '$$this.v'
                }
            }
        }
    } },
    { '$sort': { 'total': -1, '_id': -1 } },
    { '$limit': 2 }
])
```

Comment: I am new to mongo , this was really helpfull

Comment: Another question, may be you can help me , is there a way to use the query as is with org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query ? It seems to be sutable for simple queries, but I wonder if I can use it for query with aggregation ?